# How to create Package in mono 2.8 its need 'mono.exe'

Tags: .net, linux, macos, mono

I am using "Mono Tools for Visual Studio - 2.8". When I am creating Package of mono it requires 'mono.exe' but it does not exist on my system. How can I get mono.exe OR there is any other way to make Package for the Linux.

I want to run my windows application on Linux and Mac.

Comment: What distribution and version of Linux?

Comment: Initially I am using fedora-10 for testing purpose.I am developing a .Net windows application and It needed to run on All OS(Linux, Mac).

Comment: Did you install Mono 2.8 runtime prior to Mono Tools?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to install mono on your windows machine in order to use mono-tools for VS.